# Using PHP to retrieve Exchange attachment is not working for ipm.task (but it's working for ipm.appointment)

Tags: php, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a problem to get the attachments of an Exchange task using PHP/EWS. For an ipm.appointment everything is working fine and I can get the attachments. For the ipm.task the property is empty.

After hours of try and error I have no idea.

For debugging I'm using the EWSEditor. Here I see that the item is very big and the attachments is not an empty collection. But the property HasAttachments is false, but why?

The result of the PHP-Script is

```
object(stdClass)#39 (9) {
["ItemId"]=>
  object(stdClass)#40 (2) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(164) "AAIARgAAAAAAGkRzkKpmEc2byACqAC/EWgkAEWYmayPoi0CgP855Sgd6HgAAAPLGlgAAEWYmayPoi0CgP855Sgd6HgAAATeKvQAALgAAAAAAGkRzkKpmEc2byACqAC/EWgMAEWYmayPoi0CgP855Sgd6HgAAAPLGlgAA"
    ["ChangeKey"]=>
    string(40) "EwAAABYAAAARZiZrI+iLQKA/znlKB3oeAAABNFP4"
  }
  ["Subject"]=>
  string(13) "auch ein test"
  ["Body"]=> ...
  ["Attachments"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Categories"]=>
  object(stdClass)#45 (1) {
    ["String"]=>
    string(3) "WWW"
  }
  ["HasAttachments"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

I know it's like a crytal ball, but I have no idea to give more details. Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Ok, I've looked into the raw XML-request and XML-response and the attachments are in the response. The problem is the property "HasAttachments", because this is still false. My PHP-script checks only this property, though the result is an empty array in PHP.

[image: EWSEditor]

This is not a problem to change my PHP-script. But why is the property HasAttachments false, although the object has attachments? Strange behaviour...

Comment: Sanity check: You are 100% certain you are looking at the same object in PHP and EWSEditor? Go and triple check...

Comment: Yes, there is only one object in this folder. I did a lot of operation to check this. Delete, create a new one, change the body of the object and so on.